# Which certificate should I use to sign my Mac OS X application?

Tags: xcode, macos, certificate, release

We are developing a Mac OS X application that we are going to distribute outside the Mac App Store. We ended up having these certificates in the Mac Developers program:

[image: List of six certificates: two of type Mac Development, four of types Developer ID Installer, Mac App Distribution, Mac Installer Distribution, Developer ID Application]

and when I go to select one for signing the application, I find this:

[image: Certificate selection menu. Automatic: Mac Developer, Mac Distribution, Developer ID: *; others in Identities in Keychain]

Am I correct in that I should use `Developer ID: *` for Debug? Will that allow developers that don’t have my company’s certificate to sign the application to be able to run it locally?

What certificate should I use for Release?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

For development (for example, the Debug configuratino) use the `Mac Developer` option, which will choose your local Mac Developer certificate (in your case "Mac Developer: José Fernández"), which is meant for team members working on your project (includes testing/debugging).

For Release, use "Developer ID: *" which will pick [the standard application release certificate used outside the AppStore](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/DistributingApplicationsOutside/DistributingApplicationsOutside.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH12-SW2), in your case "Developer ID Application: Carousel Apps. I recommend doing a final test/debug after codesigning to ensure it's working as expected.

The way Xcode picks up certificates is by a simple substring matching.

### [Apple Codesigning Certificate Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH31-SW41)

(**Name**, *Type*, Description)

**iOS Development**

- *iPhone Developer*: Team Member Name Used to run an iOS app on devices
  and use certain app services during development.

**iOS Distribution**

- *iPhone Distribution*: 
  Team Name Used to distribute your iOS app on
  designated devices for testing or to submit it to the App Store.

**Mac Development**

- *Mac Developer*: Team Member Name Used to enable certain app services
  during development and testing.

**Mac App Distribution**

- *3rd Party Mac Developer Application*: Team Name Used to sign a Mac app
  before submitting it to the Mac App Store.

**Mac Installer Distribution**

- *3rd Party Mac Developer Installer*: Team Name Used to sign and submit
  a Mac Installer Package, containing your signed app, to the Mac App
  Store.

**Developer ID Application**

- *Developer ID Application*: Team Name Used to sign a Mac app before
  distributing it outside the Mac App Store.

**Developer ID Installer**

- *Developer ID Installer*: Team Name Used to sign and distribute a Mac
  Installer Package, containing your signed app, outside the Mac App
  Store

[image]
Once codesigned you can also simulate the launch behavior of your app when Gatekeeper is enabled from `Terminal.app`:

```
spctl -a -v Carousel.app

./Carousel.app: accepted
source=Developer ID
```

> The `Developer ID Application` certificate allows your app to run with
>   `Gatekeeper` on the setting **"allow apps downloaded from Mac App Store
>   and identified developers"**

Comment: When you say it would be correct, do you mean for Release or Debug? You are talking about the Mac Apple Store, but we are not going to distribute our app through the Mac Apple Store. Does it change your answer?

Comment: If you're not concerned whether users get a warning when they try and open your app then you can choose not to codesign it at all outside the AppStore — I wouldn't recommend doing that though.

Comment: I thought that Developer ID: * would sign it with my own certificate, not my company's. Why does Apple release personal certificates?

Comment: Or rather, how do I get it to compile on a developer's machine that doesn't have my company's certificate?

Comment: I'm finding this quite confusing, I say "Is it ok to use Developer ID *" and you said "Yes, it's ok to use Developer ID Application" when Developer ID * and Developer ID Application are two separate entries in that list. Furthermore, using Developer ID * prevents other developers to be able to sign the app for local use, so, it doesn't seem to be the right approach for Debugging purposes.

Comment: If I understand correctly your question is — "Which certificate to use during development, and testing (for team members) and which one to use for release outside the AppStore as my official company?"

Comment: Yes, by the Debug configuration I meant individual developers to run the apps on their machines. And by Release I meant the product to be distributed (but not on the Mac Store). I'm using Debug and Release as the name of different configurations you can have in Xcode.

Comment: Ah, okay, fully understand now - Then for development/debug (meant for team members) use the `Mac Development` certificate and the `Developer ID Application` for when you release and distribute your app outside the AppStore as your company. Look near the bottom of this page at the section ["Your Signing Certificates in Depth"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH31-SW32), it summarizes and outlines it fairly well.

Comment: It's notable that for those who are a part of an organization, only the team agent can create a "Developer ID Application" certificate and only a team admin (or agent) can download certificates. I learned the hard way that you can't just send .cer files to team members because the user ID doesn't match and no paired private key is created. And at least for our organization that type of cert wasn't there by default.

Comment: Xcode 11 moved to a pair of unified development and distribution certificates that work across all Apple platforms (including Mac Catalyst apps).

Answer (score 0):

To code sign via the terminal (if not using Xcode):

codesign -s "Developer ID" -v Carousel.app # to sign with "Developer ID Application" for distribution

codesign -s "Mac Developer" -v CarouselDebug.app # to sign with "Mac Developer:*" for testing

spctl -a -v Carousel.app # to verify, look for "accepted"

spctl -a -v CarouselDebug.app # to verify, look for "accepted"

Codesign finds the correct certificate by looking for certificates in your keychain that have the -s string as a substring.  If only more than one certificate matches, it will warn you and you can give a longer string.

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/Procedures/Procedures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005929-CH4-SW4