# distribute software for MAC OS with developer certificate

Tags: macos, app-store, app-store-connect

I had developer application for MAC desktop.
I would like to submit it to client for testing.

But not able to find the steps for developer distribution.

Like iphone application :- we register the UDID of the device (iphone/iPAD) and then add those in the provisioning profile and then create the ipa.

How do we create developer ipa file for mac desktop version.

please help.
I am new to mac os application

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which certificate should I use to sign my Mac OS X application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29039462/which-certificate-should-i-use-to-sign-my-mac-os-x-application)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple guides about distributing Mac OS applications. "[Distributing your Mac Apps](https://developer.apple.com/osx/distribution/)" is the main entry point.

If you want to distribute your app to client just to test you can sign app with Developer ID certificate. In this case you need to investigate this certain chapter "[Distributing Applications Outside the Mac App Store](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/DistributingApplicationsOutside/DistributingApplicationsOutside.html)".

Separately you have option to export application bundle without any signing.
Short steps:

- Select menu item Product->Archive
- Click Export button
- Select "Export as Mac Application"
- Click Next and save your app