# What is the purpose of Apple Development and Apple Distribution certificates?

Tags: xcode, macos, certificate, mac-app-store

What is the purpose of **Apple Development** and **Apple Distribution** certificates for macOS application?

It is quite new types of certificates in addition to existing `iOS/Mac Development/Distribution`.

According to the documentation:

- **Apple Development** — For macOS apps, use app services during development and testing.
- **Apple Distribution** — For macOS apps, sign an app before distributing it through the Mac App Store.

https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev154b28f09?sub=dev23755c6c6

What does it mean `sign an app before distributing` because for distributing it through the Mac App Store I have to use **Mac App Distribution** (the name is `3rd Party Mac Developer Application`) and **Mac Installer Distribution** (the name is `3rd Party Mac Developer Installer`).

Awesome but a bit outdated explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29040068/1785926